# Accessing enviroment variables from a linked container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I would like to find out how to access the environment variables from a linked docker container. I would like to access the host/port in my node app from a linked rethinkdb container. Using docker compose (bluemixservice and rethinkdb):

```
version: '2'
services:
  twitterservice:
    build: ./workerTwitter
    links:
      - mongodb:mongolink
      - rabbitmq:rabbitlink
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
  bluemixservice:
    build: ./workerBluemix
    links: 
      - rabbitmq:rabbitlink
      - rethinkdb:rethinkdb
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - rethinkdb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/var/lib/mongo
    command: mongod
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'
  rethinkdb:
      image: rethinkdb:latest
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        - "28015:28015"
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
  rethink-data:
    driver: local
```

I would like to access them in my pm2 processes.json:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "sentiment-service",
            "script": "./src",
            "merge_logs": true,
            "max_restarts": 40,
            "restart_delay": 10000,
            "instances": 1,
            "max_memory_restart": "200M",
            "env": {
                "PORT": 8080,
                "NODE_ENV": "production",
                "RABBIT_MQ": "amqp://rabbitlink:5672/",
                "ALCHEMY_KEY": "xxxxxxx",
                "RETHINK_DB_HOST": "Rethink DB Container Hostname?",
                "RETHINK_DB_PORT": "Rethink DB Container Port?",
                "RETHINK_DB_AUTHKEY": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This used to be possible (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/)), but now the suggestion is to just use the linked service name as hostname, as you are already doing in your example with rabbitmq. Regarding port numbers, I don't think it adds much to use variables for that; I'd just go with the plain number. You can however [parameterize the whole `docker-compose.yml` using variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) in case you want to be able to quickly change a value from outside.

Note that there is no need to alias links, I find it much clearer to just use the service name.

Also, a `links` already implies `depends_on`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using consul to and registrator to detect all my containers.

```
version: '2'
services:
  consul:
    command: -server -bootstrap -advertise 192.168.99.101
    image: progrium/consul:latest
    ports:
      - 8300:8300
      - 8400:8400  # rpc/rest
      - 8500:8500  # ui
      - 8600:53/udp   # dns
  registrator:
    command: -ip=192.168.99.101 consul://consul:8500
    image: gliderlabs/registrator:latest
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock"
    links:
      - consul
  twitterservice:
    build: ./workerTwitter
    container_name: twitterservice
    links:
      - mongodb:mongolink
      - rabbitmq:rabbitlink
      - consul
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
      - consul
  bluemixservice:
    build: ./workerBluemix
    container_name: bluemixservice
    links: 
      - rabbitmq:rabbitlink
      - rethinkdb:rethinkdb
      - consul
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - rethinkdb
      - consul
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    links:
      - consul
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/var/lib/mongo
    command: mongod
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'
    links:
      - consul
    depends_on:
      - consul
  rethinkdb:
      image: rethinkdb:latest
      container_name: rethinkdb
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        - "28015:28015"
      links:
      - consul
      depends_on:
      - consul
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
  rethink-data:
    driver: local
```